# I created the tags (surface-integrals) and (line-integrals)

Tags: discussion, tagging

I created the tags [(surface-integrals)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/surface-integrals) and [(line-integrals)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/line-integrals).

I had created the (line-integrals) before and had wrote its wiki only to have the tag deleted by someone and consequently the wiki itself.

I feel like these tags are useful (and necessary too, but necessity isn't a necessary reason to create a tag). I don't feel like explaining why I find these tags useful. I'm just letting the community know the tags were created, now do as you see fit.

Comment: If you don't feel like explaining why you find these tags useful, what makes you believe that they won't be removed a second time?

Comment: Nothing, I'm saying I don't care. Do as you wish.

Comment: Okay, I really don't understand what's going on here. On the one hand you care enough to create these tags in the first place, recreate them when they get deleted, and create this thread to discuss it. On the other hand, you don't care enough to explain why these tags should stay. ???

Comment: @NajibIdrissi That's right. It's too much of a hassle to justify myself. I created the tags because I think they're good. If the community doesn't care/agree, that's the community's problem (in my eyes, of course). I have provided a service which you're now free to use or dismiss.

Comment: So that this information is not lost in the case the tags are deleted - line-integrals: [tag-excerpt](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1022704/revisions) and [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1022703/revisions)
surface-integrals: [tag-excerpt](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1022706/revisions) and [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1022705/revisions). Although it might be possible to dig out the same information [using SEDE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242090/)  if the tags last at least until one data dump.

Comment: @MartinSleziak So I'm guessing that the wikis I wrote for the line-integral tag the first time didn't survive.

Comment: Well, even if the tag was deleted, you can find the [revision history](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/962607/revisions). But (since I did not find the tag-wiki in SEDE - you can try for yourself), the only thing I could do would be checking edits on your activity tab. (Which would take a lot of time without knowing at least approximately when the tag-wiki was created.) See the link to meta.SE in my previous comment for more details.

Comment: I have no opinion on whether the tags should stay or go, but this post is a fine example of passive aggression. Perhaps come back and review it tomorrow with a cooler mindset?

Comment: *I don't care. Do as you wish* - [What do you mean](http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_mdz5qe7skS1rlonnxo1_500.png) ?

Comment: @Lucian I don't believe your question is in good faith and for that reason I will not answer.

Comment: @Lucian But you did not shoot those movies yourself, did you? The wiki was something GG wrote, I assume.

Comment: @Lucian I don't even care that what I copied from wikipedia was lost. And replying to the passive-aggressive remark above, my rationale is the following. I created the tags. I'm half expecting people to find them useless. Instead of trying to justify myself and getting bothered by it, I merely let the community know that this 'harm' was done instead of trying to hide it by not announcing it. I'm basically taking responsibility for the creation of the tags. If people decide they want to remove the tags, I honestly don't care.

Comment: And for my decision of publicly announcing the creation of the tags, I did it because a user decide one of them shouldn't exist. So I brought it up to the community. Plus there's [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17016/whats-the-formal-proofs-tag-for#comment62905_17016) previous experience of not announcing it. [This](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17023/should-every-new-tag-be-discussed-on-meta-before-creation) question is also relevant. Maybe next time I'll just do nothing, now that's passive-aggression.

Comment: @GitGud There is a middle way: post an answer in the Tag Cleanup 2014 thread. (That thread should probably be named Tag Maintenance to better reflect the scope... but that can wait until 2015 version rolls out.)

Answer (score 16):

I support the introduction of both tags. Problems involving line integrals and surface integrals are quite different from ordinary integration problems in that the difficulty usually lies not in finding an antiderivative but in finding a parametrization and correctly combining it with a given function. Having tags for such questions will bring more structure to the vast sea of calculus questions.

Comment: Just how can there be such a big discrepancy in the votes to this answer and the votes to the question, when they support the same thing?

Comment: I suppose that the perceived value of a meta post depends not only on the position taken, but also on the argument, if any, given in support of the position.